Simplifying DAX Statement
In order to get data from the MSFT Teams Call Quality Data warehouse (OLAP). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/dimensions-and-measures-available-in-call-quality-dashboard
There are a bunch of restrictions:
The PBI connector only works in desktop mode, not in the cloud
It makes a DirectQuery Connection
It cannot handle anything other than the simplest DAX (only SUM, MAX) no MEAN, AVG, etc.
It chops the result at 10K rows (so Ineed to find a way to do multiple EVALAUTES)
I have something working in DAX studio, but DAX allows only one DEFINE for Multiple EVALAUTES, is there a way to factor out some of the common terms with VAR or MEASURE so that I can trim the EVALAUTE just to deal with CQD[End Time]

EVALUATE
    CALCULATETABLE(
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
            CQD[Second Network Name],
            CQD[Second Subnet],
            CQD[Date],
            CQD[Day Of Week],
            CQD[Hour],
            CQD[Total Call Count],
            CQD[Avg Network Jitter Max],
            CQD[Audio Poor Percentage],
            CQD[Video Poor Percentage],
            CQD[Avg Round Trip Max]
        ),
        CQD[Stream Direction] = "First-to-Second",
        CQD[CDR Response Reason] = "OK",
        CQD[First UserType] = "Server",
        CQD[Second Inside Corp] = "Inside",
        CQD[Second Network Connection Detail] = "Wired",
        CQD[Test Call Type] = "NonTest",
        CQD[Session Type] = "Conf",
        CQD[Is Server Pair] IN {
            "Client : Server",
            " : Client"
        },
        CQD[Second UserType] IN {
            "User",
            "Anonymous"
        },
        NOT (CQD[Packet Utilization] IN {
            "(Blank)",
            "062: [0 - 0]",
            "064: [1 - 2)"
        }),
        AND(
            CQD[End Time] >= dt"2024-07-17T00:00:00",
            CQD[End Time] < dt"2024-07-17T18:00:00"    
        )
    )


Wrap what you want to define as filters in the DEFINE, then reference them in each EVALUATE.
DEFINE
        VAR CommonFilters = 
            FILTER(
                CQD,
                CQD[Stream Direction] = "First-to-Second" &&
                CQD[CDR Response Reason] = "OK" &&
                CQD[First UserType] = "Server" &&
                CQD[Second Inside Corp] = "Inside" &&
                CQD[Second Network Connection Detail] = "Wired" &&
                CQD[Test Call Type] = "NonTest" &&
                CQD[Session Type] = "Conf" &&
                CQD[Is Server Pair] IN {"Client : Server", " : Client"} &&
                CQD[Second UserType] IN {"User", "Anonymous"} &&
                NOT (CQD[Packet Utilization] IN {"(Blank)", "062: [0 - 0]", "064: [1 - 2)"})
            )
        VAR EndTimeFilter1 = 
            FILTER(
                CommonFilters,
                CQD[End Time] >= dt"2024-07-17T00:00:00" &&
                CQD[End Time] < dt"2024-07-17T06:00:00"
            )
        VAR EndTimeFilter2 = 
            FILTER(
                CommonFilters,
                CQD[End Time] >= dt"2024-07-17T06:00:00" &&
                CQD[End Time] < dt"2024-07-17T12:00:00"
            )
        VAR EndTimeFilter3 = 
            FILTER(
                CommonFilters,
                CQD[End Time] >= dt"2024-07-17T12:00:00" &&
                CQD[End Time] < dt"2024-07-17T18:00:00"
            )
    
    EVALUATE
        CALCULATETABLE(
            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
                CQD[Second Network Name],
                CQD[Second Subnet],
                CQD[Date],
                CQD[Day Of Week],
                CQD[Hour],
                CQD[Total Call Count],
                CQD[Avg Network Jitter Max],
                CQD[Audio Poor Percentage],
                CQD[Video Poor Percentage],
                CQD[Avg Round Trip Max]
            ),
            EndTimeFilter1
        )
    
    EVALUATE
        CALCULATETABLE(
            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
                CQD[Second Network Name],
                CQD[Second Subnet],
                CQD[Date],
                CQD[Day Of Week],
                CQD[Hour],
                CQD[Total Call Count],
                CQD[Avg Network Jitter Max],
                CQD[Audio Poor Percentage],
                CQD[Video Poor Percentage],
                CQD[Avg Round Trip Max]
            ),
            EndTimeFilter2
        )
    
    EVALUATE
        CALCULATETABLE(
            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
                CQD[Second Network Name],
                CQD[Second Subnet],
                CQD[Date],
                CQD[Day Of Week],
                CQD[Hour],
                CQD[Total Call Count],
                CQD[Avg Network Jitter Max],
                CQD[Audio Poor Percentage],
                CQD[Video Poor Percentage],
                CQD[Avg Round Trip Max]
            ),
            EndTimeFilter3
        )

